# Mexican vaccine certificate to enter the EU

Tags: eu, mexico, vaccinations

Mexican vaccine certificates contain only the name of the vaccine (e.g. Astrazeneca / Pfizer) and not where it was produced. The EU offers entry exemptions to "fully vaccinated travellers from outside of the Union" as defined [here](https://www.government.nl/topics/coronavirus-covid-19/visiting-the-netherlands-from-abroad/requirements-for-proof-of-vaccination), and many countries require a health entry form to be completed (e.g. [here](https://www.government.nl/binaries/government/documenten/publications/2021/07/01/vaccine-declaration-covid-19/vaccine-declarationform-20220208.pdf)).

The proof of vaccination requires specification of *which* vaccine (e.g. Astrazeneca EU vaxzevria / Astrazeneca - Japan vaxzevria etc) which is not demonstrable through the Mexican vaccine passport. Does anyone have experience of entering the EU with a certificate issued in Mexico and if so, how to determine the correct vaccine origin for the entry form?

Comment: Do you have a copy of the vaccine record saying what kind of vaccine it was?

Comment: Just the name astrazeneca appears

Comment: I wonder if this question might be more answerable without being focused on Mexican vaccine certificates specifically? The issue appears to be vaccine certificates that don't mention origin of vaccine and potentially other countries than just Mexico have certificates like these and may have had travelers flying to Europe...

Comment: Yes I agree - I will happily edit the question

Comment: I don’t know if this is a reliable source but looking at this list of the vaccines approved for use in Mexico https://covid19.trackvaccines.org/country/mexico/ should help identify the correct brand name to complete the entry form

Comment: Note that the rules vary per country. Sweden basically requires a EU-compatible vaccination certificate or a US one. You can enter the Schengen area but not EU via Norway with nothing. You can enter Denmark with just a test instead of vaccination. You can enter all three from EU/Schengen countries with zero Covid documentation. It is not much help going to the Netherlands since they don't allow free travel from EU/Schengen, but there won't be a common answer for all of EU to this question.

Comment: @Traveller that page has broken links, which don't help, but also doesn't appear to give the place of manufacture for the different vaccines

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the EU no longer requires vaccine certificates.

Comment: @JonathanReez You do realise that many countries still require vaccination and/or testing for travelers to enter.  Possibly other reasons for a close, but "because the pandemic is now over" doesn't really work when there are countries that still have pandemic requirements

Comment: @Midavalo yes, sadly there's still a few holdouts. Edited the close reason.